# Derive the labour demand function.

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, economics

$$Y = 4[(K^α)(L^{(1-α)})]$$

I took the derivative with respect to $L$, and ended up with:

$$Y'= 4[(K^α)(1-α)L^{(-α)}$$

But the correct answer is something like:
$$[4(1-a)K^a/w]^{(1/a)}$$

I'm not totally sure where the $w$ came from but my guess is MP of labor $= w$, where $w =$ wages.

Please show me the correct method.

Comment: I edited your post to make the $\LaTeX$ render properly.  Note that $\LaTeX$ should be enclosed in "\$" signs, *viz.* "\$ \alpha \$" yields $ \alpha $.  I hope I got your intentions right.  If not, feel free to change it.  Also, what is $w$?

Comment: What's the context? Is this within a General equilibrium model, or you simply need to compute the demand for labor for a given firm with no reference to other markets?

Comment: It's within a general equilibrium.

Comment: Then you should add that into your post. Anyway, you are on the right track. In a competitive GE model the demand for labor can be obtained by equating Marginal product of labor to labor wage and then solving the resulting equation for L. So just take your derivative of Y with respect to labor, set it equal to w and solve the resulting equation for L.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a unit price $p=1$ the profit function becomes
$$G=4K^\alpha L^{1-\alpha}-cK-wL$$
where w is the wage. Maximize the profit with respect to $L$
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial L}=4K^\alpha (1-\alpha)L^{-\alpha}-w=0$$
and solve for $L$
$$L=\big(4 (1-\alpha) K^\alpha /w \big)^{1/\alpha}$$